# Can't find folder on tablet but on phone [Android]

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, directory

I'am trying to find a folder on my TABLET.

I am able to find the folder on my PHONE using this code:

```
 File settingsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), settingsFileDirectory);
```

I can find the folder on my phone but not on my tablet, what's going on there?

Created a folder with the same name in the same directory (sameas the downloads folder).

Greets

Comment: What do you mean by "find the folder"? You are creating a `File` object... then doing nothing with it, based on the single line of code in your question.

Comment: What's the sdk version of both your tablet and phone?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

use

```
context.getFilesDir().getPath() + ....destination...
```

Example

```
new File(
context.getFilesDir().getPath()
+ "/settings"
+ "/happyness");
```

Comment: Hey Mohammed, I am trying now to get a file in the download directory of the phone/tablet by using your code but my app crashes.


String path = this.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/Download";

Comment: @Jannick please update your post with the error and the line of codes so I could help you better :)